# How to do a custom JSON Marshaller in a Jersey web app?

Tags: java, jersey

I am running a web application using Jersey. In my controller, I am trying to get a file in resources and also return an object which contains an `enum`. The `enum` also has two fields inside it. When the object is being marshalled, I am getting errors:

```
jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:541)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:196)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:80)
    at com.jtv.insights.controller.IngestionController.getIngestionLogDetails(IngestionController.java:194)
```

My code is:

```
@GET
@Path(value = "/log/details/{fileId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<IngestionLogs> getIngestionLogDetails(@PathParam("fileId") String fileId) {
    List<IngestionLogs> logs = new ArrayList<>();
    // added data in list
    try {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { IngestionLogs.class });
        Marshaller jsonMarshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
        jsonMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jsonMarshaller.setAdapter(new LogsAdapter());
        jsonMarshaller.marshal(logs, response.getOutputStream());
        return logs;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

My object is:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LogsAdapter.class)
public class IngestionLogs {
    private LogType type;
    private String message;
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;
    private String fileName;
    private int rowNumber;
    private int columnNumber;
    private String cellValue;
    private String columnName;
    // getters & setters
}
```

How do I fix this error, create a custom function which marshalls my object and return this list as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the properties map and your class com.jtv.insights.tool.model.IngestionLogs needs to have a default constructor without parameters (public IngestionLogs() {}).

Comment: The enum has values which needs to be flattened in the `IngestionLogs`. How do I create a custom Marshaller function?

Comment: After doing your suggestion, I am getting `jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.`

Comment: Is there a field or getter in IngestionLogs that is or returns an ArrayList<>? That should be changed to List then.

Comment: `IngestionLogs` has fields which are String, int, LocalDateTime and enums.

Comment: I have added the bean class also in the question.

Comment: Please also add LogType; IngestionLogs seems to be fine.